# Can the "as" keyword be used to explicitly state a type for key/values?

Tags: swift, dictionary

Using Firebase to save a user with a unique id, username and email just as part of the login process.
When creating the user, the data pieces are saved in a dictionary, and at the end of this declaration of the dictionary it has "`as [String: Any]`"

```
   let values = ["username": username, "email": email, "id": uid!] as [String: Any]
```

From what I know the `as` keyword is used to downcast from one type to another but here it seems to just be stating what types the keys and values have. Is that correct? I think I am missing something though, as if that were the case, wouldn't that be possible for the compiler to infer and so the `as` would be kinda redundant?

Is this `as [String: Any]` just for clarity then?

Comment: Actually in this case, the `as` keyword achieves upcasting, not downcasting, since `Any` can represent any Swift type. It can be used for upcasting, downcasting and bridge casting as well. For more information, have a look at [Type casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html).

Comment: Yep - I had searched SO but didn't see this - the answer by jtbandes in the link provided by Honey does answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler can infer the type of `values` by itself but in some cases, specially with `[String: Any]` objects, to explicitly declare the type improves compilation time [significantly](https://medium.com/@johnsundell/improving-swift-compile-times-ee1d52fb9bd).

In this case the `as [String: Any]` could be both for clarity and performance.